# Python change object reference from object itself

Tags: python, class, oop, reference

Consider the following code:

```
class A:
    def hi(self):
        print 'A'
    def change(self):
        self = B()
class B(A):
    def hi(self):
        print 'B'
```

and

```
test = A()
test.hi() -> prints A
test.change()
test.hi() -> prints A, should print B
```

Is there some way to make this principle work, so changing the object reference 'test' from withing the class/object itself?

Comment: You're changing a local variable `self` not the instance.

Comment: I am aware of that, however i am looking for a solution to change the instance from within the object/class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects have no concept of the variable that contains them - thus, you can't do exactly what you're trying to do.

What you could do is have a container that is aware of the thing it contains:

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.thing = A()
    def change(self):
        self.thing = B()
    def hi(self):
        self.thing.hi()

test = Container()
test.hi() # prints A
test.change()
test.hi() # prints B
```